# Is Detect Kuji Shrines actually useful?

Tags: mini-ninjas

I have been playing Mini Ninjas, and acquired the "Detect Kuji Shrine" spell. I tried to use it, but found that the little fireflies/yellow flying sparkly things that it creates move too quickly to really follow, and often it is easier to find the hidden shrines by just looking for the regular fireflies that indicate hidden surprises/secrets.

Am I just using the spell incorrectly? Or will it show me things that the fireflies don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that it [has been a while](http://live.xbox.com/en-US/GameCenter/Achievements?titleId=1396901860&compareTo=DL%20CyberSkull) since I last played *Mini Ninjas*. It is useful to the extent that you can use it point you in the right direction. All the spell does is point you to the fire flies. Most you should run across yourself, but a few are out of the way. As for expending ki, there are plenty of powerups even on hard difficulty. The spell should only lead you to Kuji Shrines, so it won't show you anything new.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question - I understand I can recast the spell, but I don't want to waste ki on it if it isn't going to show me anything more than the fireflies I run across.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Answer updated.